# How to use resource files in Xamarin from other NuGet packages?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, nuget

I need to slice an existing Xamarin app with both Android and iOS flavours into NuGet packages, with each package containing a module that brings its own UI (fragments, viewcontrollers) that shall incorporate itself into the main application's UI.

Currently I am at the point where I need to reference Android resources in one package that are defined in another NuGet package. It works fine in code, where I can just use the respective namespace of the generated *Resource* class, but it does not from within Android resource files, i.e. (a)xml.

Ultimately I will need to slice the iOS parts as well, but I have only reached the Android part, yet.

At least for Android, it should be possible, because it does work for Xamarin provided support libraries. But I have seen that it is a binding to an .aar file. But building an .aar file in order to bind it would defeat the purpose of building the UI in Xamarin, so this is not really a feasible workaround.

Here is an example of what does not even compile:

Resources/values/colors.xml in Project/NuGet package A:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="TextColor">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Resources/values/styles.xml in Project B, referencing NuGet package A:

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <style name="ExampleDescription">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/TextColor</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Where A is an android library and B is an android application.

Can anyone provide any input or ideas on how to achieve the desired result? Maybe give some hints about doing it in iOS as well?

Comment: ,According to your description, you want to reference another nuget package in project, then use resource file from this nuget package in project? If yes, I suggest you can take a look:https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/141666/use-the-old-style-nuget-package-reference

Comment: @CherryBu thanks, but the linked question/answer is about referencing local packages. Local packaging we can deal with, but it does not solve the problem of resolving references in the xml's into the linked NuGet packages.

Comment: Could you please explain it further